# Bump map in "non-color" mode has inconsistent gray in image editor + 3D view?

Tags: texture-painting, bump

The blend is simple: Default cube, add a shader node to the material to do image texture -> bump -> material normals. I add a new texture for the bump map at 50% gray, and I can paint black lines on the object, and then if I paint a 50% gray in either the image editor or 3d view, it has the same effect, where it "erases" the stroke and resets the texture to default value.

The issue is that from what I see online, you should really use "non-color" mode for the image texture being used for the bump map. But when I switch an image to non-color mode, the 50% gray now shows as ~75% gray in the image editor. And the real issue is that using a 50% gray brush now gives different results based on the view, if I paint with the 50% gray brush in the image editor, it "erases" to the color that's visibly ~75% gray, but if I use that same brush in the 3d view to paint on the model, it actually depresses the bump map (and sets it in the image editor to a visibly 50% gray color). So in other words the same brush just sets the bump to different heights based on if it's used in the 3d view or the image view.

Is there something I need to set to make this not happen with non-color images? Or is this just an unfortunate side effect?
[image]

Comment: Hello ! A few screenshots would go a long way to explain your problem :)

Comment: I was looking to add a .blend but couldn't see the option to attach files to the post, sorry. But here's a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/MTkokJK.png . Dunno how expressive it is, but basically, the image on the left was made at 50% gray, then made non-color. When I use a 50% gray brush, if used on the paint panel it "erases" the black line (the gap seen). If I use the same brush on the 3d view, it instead results in the darker stroke. I assume this has something to do with the "non-color" texture made at 50% gray showing up as lighter than actually 50% gray.

Comment: Oh, okay that makes sense. Maye try to tweak the view transform in the render properties ?

Comment: Hey, that (basically) actually worked, thanks! Looked that up, went to Render Properties->Color Management, changed View Transform, and it didn't do anything, same issue. But "Display Device" in Color Management was defaulted to "sRGB", and when I set that to "None" instead, the painting worked as expected in both views. It darkens the model in the viewport / looks a bit off, but since this is just for making+exporting a model, that's fine.